# PHPExcel set font name in header/footer

Tags: fonts, phpexcel

I tried 
 `$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&"Arial,Bold"&C&B&7Seite &P aus &N');`

But I still get Calibri as font name instead of Arial.

Answer (score 0):

The command actually looks like

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()
    ->setOddHeader('&C&H&25INTERVIEW WORKSHEET');
```

where the symbols are in 4.6.13 of the developer doc (Word document) which can be found at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=54983

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getFont() on string

Comment: Removed the oddheaderfooter for now.

Comment: $sheet->getHeaderFooter()->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Arial')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('6F6F6F');  produces  Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooter::getFont() i

Comment: I guess formatting of header and footer is done via this block  - http://kagda.ru/i/7101110971898_02-07-2017-16:10:33_7101.png .But I didn't find a way to use it properly for setting font. It claims that  "&" is responsible for it

Comment: I saw it before and tried it (without luck), how am I to set it for get arial bold font applied? Error must in synstactic I believe